# How come this Python code does not work under my class function?

Tags: python, class, undefined

I ran this on Jupyter notebook. It should print the assignments in the print function. It gives the error:

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
         in 
        ----> 1 class Car:
          2 
          3     sportscar = Car()
          4     van = Car()
          5     truck = Car()

```
    <ipython-input-12-ff9e58e0b68d> in Car()
      1 class Car:
      2  
     ----> 3     sportscar = Car()
      4     van = Car()
      5     truck = Car()

    NameError: name 'Car' is not defined
```

How can car not be defined under the class?

```
class Car:

sportscar = Car()
van = Car()
truck = Car()
compact_car = Car()


sportscar.color = 'red'
sportscar.interior = 'leather'
sportscar.windows ='dark tint'
sportscar.top_speed ='150 mph'

van.color = 'gray'
van.interior = 'carpet'
van.windows = 'clear'
van.top_speed = '80 mph'

truck.color = 'midnight blue'
truck.interior = 'leather'
truck.windows = 'tint'
truck.top_speed = '100 mph'

compact_car.color ='white'
compact_car.interior = 'leather'
compact_car.windows = 'clear'
compact_car.top_speed = '90 mph'

print(sportscar.windows)
print(van.windows)
print(truck.color)
print(compact_car.color)
```

Comment: Why create those  `Car`s inside of `Car`? I think you want to put that code outside of `Car`.

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: You can't have an empty class block like that. Try indenting `pass` under `class Car:` Since whitespace is critical in Python, it's hard to know what you are trying to do if your indentation is not correct in the question body.

Comment: @MarkMeyer That's not the problem. That's a pasting error.

Comment: You're misusing classes here. You should have a `Car` class that has `color`, `interior` etc attributes, then create the `van` an such out side of `Car`.

Comment: I did that. It wont give me an output.

Comment: @MichaelPaxinos make sure the indentation in your question matches your code, other side we are just guessing.

Comment: @Carcigenicate. But my instances of the class Car are sportscar, van, truck, and compact_car. Shouldn't my instances go first , and then the attributes?

Comment: You are misunderstanding how to use classes. You first define your Car class (what a Car is, define attributes) then outside of your class, create instances of your Car class (Car objects). See the Python docs on [A First Look on Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes).

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `Car` class to look like this:

```
# This class is where the problem was
class Car:
    def __init__(self): # The class just needs to be initialized
        pass
```

The reason Python couldn't find the `Car` class was that it was never initialized, so it was as if it had never been declared.